# How to Create Test Cases and Data Point Validators for Scrapy Web Scraper

Tags: python, unit-testing, validation, testing, scrapy

I have created a scrapy web scraper but I have no idea how to create **Test cases and Data point validators** for this web scraper.

I have **three interconnected parsers**:

```
def parse(self, response):

    urls = response.xpath('').extract()
     
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_company_index)
```

```
def parse_company_index(self, response):

    print("procesing:"+response.url)
    name = response.xpath('').extract()

    urls = response.xpath('').extract()

    data = zip(name, urls)
    for item in data:
        dict = {
            'record_type': 'company_index',
            'company_name': item[0],
            'source_url': item[1],
        }
        yield dict
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_company_profiles)

    next_page = response.xpath('').get()
    if next_page is not None:
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse_company_index)
```

```
def parse_company_profiles(self, response):
    Company_name = response.xpath('').extract()

    Company_location = response.xpath('').extract()
    

    Company_website = response.xpath('').extract()

    Company_webdomain = response.xpath('').extract()

    Company_industry = response.xpath('').extract()

    Company_employee_size = response.xpath('').extract()

    Company_revenue = response.xpath('').extract()

    Contact_name = response.xpath('').extract()
    
    Contact_jobtitle = response.xpath('').extract()

    Contact_email_domain = response.xpath('').extract()

    Contact_detail = []
    if Contact_name:
        for i in range(len(Contact_name)):
            Contact_detail.append({'Contact_name': Contact_name[i],
                                'Contact_jobtitle': Contact_jobtitle[i],
                                'Contact_email_domain': Contact_email_domain[i]})
        Contact_details = [Contact_detail]
    else:
        Contact_details = ["None"]

    data = zip(Company_name, Company_location, Company_website, Company_webdomain, Company_industry,
               Company_employee_size, Company_revenue, Contact_details)

    for item in data:
        dict = {
            'record_type': 'company_profiles',
            'company_name': item[0],
            'company_location': item[1],
            'company_website': item[2],
            'company_webdomain': item[3],
            'company_industry': item[4],
            'company_employee_size': item[5],
            'company_revenue': item[6],
            'contact_details': item[7]
        }
        yield dict
```

I first thought that it means creating a unittest but now that I think about it, it does not look like it. Also, if it is unittest what approach should I take to tackle this problem?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can check pydantic for writing Data point validators for web scrapers.
https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/